# connect jQuery Mobile Application to server database and open popup when internet connection off

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing Mobile Application using jQuery Mobile and phonegap.

My first question is

***1.***  In this application I required server side integration. I have my own server. The thing I need is in my application there is page called as a images so I need to connect this page with my server database so every time when I upload images on my server database the app get automatically updated.

Second question is:

***2.*** I want to open a website inside my application.when internet connection is off then a popup show with error message

I try this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Website</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {

}
// alert dialog dismissed
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}
function checkReachability() {
    var _check=true;

    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    //alert('Connection type: '+ networkState + states[networkState]);
    if(networkState==="unknown"){
        _check=false;
        showAlert();
        return _check;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert("Please connect your device to Internet.",onDeviceReady,"No Network Connectivity","OK");
}
</script>
<div data-role="content">
<iframe id="content" src="www.google.com" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; left:0px; top:40px; margin:0px; padding:0px; frameborder:0; border-width:0; border-style:hidden;">         </iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
I tested on Android 2.3 and 4.1 but does not any popup when internet connection is off.
```

Comment: Where are you calling checkReachability()? I recommend call before your ajax requests.

Comment: checkReachability() is there

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a client side function that triggers itself every few seconds, that requests a list of images and in case of an error pops a warning:

```
setInterval(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ping.php',
            data: {
                attribute_1:attribute_1,
                attribute_2:attribute_2
                },
            success: function(data){
                //process image list
            },
            error:  function(){
                //trigger popup
            }
        });
    },3000
);
```

EDIT:
For the image process step, you should compare the image list to the client side list, and check for new images, because you don't want to update all images at every ajax call.

You can also specify a timeout for the ajax call, for instance:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(textStatus==="timeout") {
            //trigger popup
        } 
    }
});
```

API documentation on $.ajax() here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/